# IIS 7 Log Files Auto Delete?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

Is there any feature in IIS 7 that automatically deletes the logs files older than a specified amt of days?

I am aware that this can be accomplished by writing a script(and run it weekly) or a windows service, but i was wondering if there is any inbuilt feature or something that does that.

Also, Currently we turned logging off as it is stacking up a large amount of space. Will that be a problem?

Comment: Not that I know of and I agree there should be. I use a PowerShell script to zip and archive them. Log files can sometimes be useful for things like getting statistics for invoicing or investigating hack attempts.

Comment: For all the upvotes, favorites, and answers, this is clearly off-topic and belongs at [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You can create a task that runs daily using Administrative Tools > Task Scheduler.

Set your task to run the following command:

```
forfiles /p "C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles" /s /m *.* /c "cmd /c Del @path" /d -7
```

This command is for IIS7, and it deletes all the log files that are one week or older.

You can adjust the number of days by changing the `/d` arg value.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Logs are already being backed up offsite so deleting old ones with this task works great for me.

Comment: simple and effective :)

Comment: perfect! and another big plus for making me aware of the `forfiles` command, thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

One line batch script:

```
forfiles /p C:\inetpub\logs /s /m *.log /d -14 /c "cmd /c del /q @file"
```

Modify the /d switch to change number of days a log file hangs around before deletion. The /s switch recurses subdirectories too.

Ref: http://debug.ga/iis-log-purging/

Answer (score 1):

Similar solution but in powershell.

I've set a task to run powershell with the following line as an Argument..

```
dir D:\IISLogs |where { ((get-date)-$_.LastWriteTime).days -gt 15 }| remove-item -force
```

It removes all files in the D:\IISLOgs folder older than 15 days.

Answer (score 0):

Another viable Powershell one-liner:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\inetpub\logs\logfiles\w3svc*\*.log | where {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-180)} | Remove-Item -force
```

In case `$_.LastWriteTime` doesn't work, you can use `$PSItem.LastWriteTime` instead.

For more info and other suggestions to leverage the IIS LogFiles folder HDD space usage, I also suggest to [read this blog post](http://www.ryadel.com/en/manage-iis-log-files-purge-older-n-days-bat-file/) that I wrote on the topic.