# Write a Batch file for automatically delete the OLD IIS log file

Tags: batch-file, iis-7, command-prompt

Whenever i want to delete the old IIS logs files on my Shared WebServer i run this command on CMD:

```
for /R C:\HostingSpaces %f in (u_ex*.log) do del /q "%~ff"
```

It searches for IIS log files and will delete all of them. For sure it can't delete the current day's log files since they are already opened in IIS and can't be deleted.
It shows me the progress of deleting log files one by one in command prompt console.

i need to set a schedule task to run a BAT file to do this automatically each day.
I have made a bat file and pasted this command within it:
for /R C:\HostingSpaces %f in (u_ex*.log) do del /q "%~ff"

But when i run the batch file nothing happens and i don't see any result and action.
How to write a batch file for running this Command?

Your help is much appreciate.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use %%A in batch files for For loops rather than %A at the command prompt.

```
del C:\HostingSpaces\u_ex*.log /s
```

is easier.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But your command won't work since the logs files are not under hostingspaces directory and they are placed within 2 level down of HOSTINGSPACES directory in sub-directories.
Thank you for your TIPs. so you mean i need to use %%f instead of %f

Comment: It will still delete them 2 levels down. Only if you have similar named files elsewhere would you not do it this way.

Comment: I am facing the problem

"The Process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

i have tried a lot by stop services and also by end process of explorer.exe

please urgent help me on emergency basis in this regards. I am facing space problem in my live server where a lot of websites are running

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest to use the `forfiles` command for the task:

```
forfiles -p C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\ -s -m *.log -d -180 -c "cmd /C DEL @File"
```

Explanation of the switches:

- -s or /S : recurse into all subfolders
- -p or /P : path
- -m or /M : file mask
- -d or /D : number of days (-180 = older than 180 days)
- -c or /C : command to execute

You can then put it into a *Scheduled Task* and have it run daily.

For a decent **Powershell** alternative, see [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40711754/1233379): for other suggestions on how to properly reduce the IIS LogFiles folder, [check out this post](http://www.ryadel.com/en/manage-iis-log-files-purge-older-n-days-bat-file/) that I wrote on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you get error is because that the current day's logs are opened in IIS.

IIS keep the current day's log open and write on it constantly. So you will not be able to delete the current day's logs.

This is the command that worked for me. My websites are all placed in a folder named `HOSTINGSPACES` and i do this to delete all of the log files (only the current day logs will remain at the end)

```
# for /R C:\HostingSpaces %f in (u_ex*.log) do del /q "%~ff"
```

`u_ex*.log` is the syntax of my logs, your logs may have another syntax, so take care of this.