# Clearing down IIS 7.5 log files - access denied

Tags: iis, command, iis-7.5, dos

I've been trying to run the command as per this post

[IIS 7 Log Files Auto Delete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919275/iis-7-log-files-auto-delete)

IE:

```
forfiles /p "C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles" /s /m *.* /c "cmd /c Del @path" /d -7
```

On Windows Server 2008 R2.
I'm logged in as a user who is a member of the administrators group, and ran the command prompt as administrator, but all I'm getting is a load of "access denied" messages coming back.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Did you try to turn off iis server before running the script?

Comment: That's a good point, but could be a problem because we have a lot of sites on the server. Surely IIS won't want to hang on to all the log file directories would it? Is there no way to clear the files down even if they are being held onto by a process. Maybe a stupid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. To answer my own question.
It seems that even though I belong to the administrators group I still needed to log in as the actual administrator in order to run this command.

Hmmmm. That seems logical... I don't think.